# Free shipping bar on slide cart is no working with all currencies

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

`{% assign freeShippingThreshold = settings.show_shipping_value | plus: 0 %} {% assign cartPrice = cart.total_price | money_without_currency | plus: 0 %} {% assign cartProgress = cartPrice | times: 100 | divided_by: freeShippingThreshold | round | plus: 0 %} {% assign difference = freeShippingThreshold | minus: cartPrice %}` 
`{% if settings.show_shipping_bar %}`

{% if cartPrice You are ${{ difference }} away from free shipping
      {% comment %} You are not eligible for free shipping {% endcomment %}
    {% else %}
      You are eligible for free shipping
    {% endif %}
    
       
    
  
{% endif %}
`

I want this code to be work with all currencies.

i apply money filter on this freeShippingThreshold but when i change the currency it will not changed the value according to the currency